# Digital voice recorder with timestamps

Tags: audio-recording

I'm looking for a digital voice recorder with these features:

- 4+ hours of recording time
- Each recording is saved as a separate audio file
- Audio files have a timestamp in the metadata
- Good audio quality

Preferrably under $50 USD, but up to $100 is okay.